# How do i continue addition with my java calculator

Tags: java

I want to add a number from my previous calculations. I currently am unable to because the loop continues.  Here is my code. For example, if i get 11 as my answer, i want to be able to add 6. I also want to be able to add 6+6 and get the answer 23. How do I do this because currently I am stuck.
Thanks for the help!

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!done){
       int numOne, numTwo, result;



       System.out.print("Enter Two Numbers : ");
       numOne = scan.nextInt();
       scan.nextLine();
       numTwo = scan.nextInt();
       scan.nextLine();


       result = numOne + numTwo;
       System.out.println("Addition = " +result);

       result = numOne - numTwo;
       System.out.println("Subtraction = " +result);

       result = numOne * numTwo;
       System.out.println("Multiplication = " +result);

       result = numOne / numTwo;
       System.out.println("Division = " +result);



       System.out.println("Enter a number for a root : ");
       double number1 = scan.nextDouble();
       scan.nextLine();
       double number2 = scan.nextDouble();
       scan.nextLine();

       System.out.println(Math.pow(number1, (1/number2)));



       System.out.println("Enter the base: ");

       long n,p,r=1;


       System.out.println("enter number");

       n=scan.nextLong();
       scan.nextLine();

       System.out.println("enter power");


       p=scan.nextLong();
       scan.nextLine();

           if(n>=0&&p==0)
       {   
          r =1;
       }
       else if(n==0&&p>=1)
       {   
            r=0;
       } 
       else
       { 
           for(int i=1;i<=p;i++)
           { 
                   r=r *n;
           } 
       }    

       System.out.println(n+"^"+p+"="+r);


       System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
       String ans2 = scan.nextLine();
       System.out.println(ans2);

       if(ans2.contains("Yes")|| ans2.contains("yes")){
                  System.out.println("Do you wish to add on to the previous calculation?");
       }
       if(ans2.contains("No") || ans2.contains("no")){
                  System.out.println("You are done calculating!");
       }
       scan.nextLine();

   }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Store the answers in different variables instead of storing everything in result.
Say 'add' is the variable used for addition then use the expression `add=add+numone+numtwo;`
Initialize add variable before the loop.
And you haven't set done variable to zero.set done=0 inside the if which checks if the choice is 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the **result** variable on top of the while loop so that it's value won't be reset everytime the loop is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the loop continues because there is no exit condition. When you write a while loop you need to make sure the condition becomes false upon achieving your objective.
To keep result persistent, declare it outside the while loop.

```
int result = 0;
    while (!done) {
```

And make the result add to itself.

```
    result += numOne + numTwo;
```

Make while condition exit when user is done calculating by setting done as true. And add another condition to reset the result when user doesn't want it anymore.

```
String ans3 = "";
if (ans2.contains("Yes") || ans2.contains("yes")) {
    System.out.println("Do you wish to add on to the previous calculation?");
    ans3 = scan.nextLine();
}
if (ans2.contains("No") || ans2.contains("no")) {
    System.out.println("You are done calculating!");
    done = true;
}
if (!ans3.toLowerCase().contains("y")) {
    result = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps